# ssis capturing errors and redirecting

Tags: email, error-handling, ssis

I have a dataflow task which reads from a file and inserts into a SQL table.  Users provide the file and can save it with out enough information (null values) etc. I don't want the package to crash i just went the users sent an email to say "Please check file is correctly formated etc "

My ssis package has an OnError and onWarning event. I've attached a script task to the onerror output of the desination control.  When an attempt is made to insert a null the Onwarning event is fired.  To stop muliple emails as the OnWarning bubbles up i have a condition prior to the email task in the OnWarning event windows.

@[System::SourceID] ==  @[System::PackageID]

I only get one email but the original error message is lost. All i get is the top level error which is something like the maximum number of errors has exceeded.  Less than usefull for the end users email.  Can i access the inner exception in my script task prior to the email task and find the inner most exception and pass it on to the email task ?

Erick

Answer (score 0):

You might consider configuring logging to write to an SQL Server table. I did this and was able to write a pretty readable, comprehensive SSRS report from the log data. The email simply alerted the appropriate person to review the log report.